# Phaser3 overlap to once tile

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs, jstilemap

I want to select 1 object in my tilemap and check whether my player hits it or not, and I can give collision in this object propslayer, there is no problem with specific objects, but I cannot get it into condition.

All I want is for example: When I hit the object with id 36, I want to print text on the consola.

```
import { Scene } from "phaser";

import Scenes from "./";
import { Player } from "../objects";

import GameManager from "../managers/gameManager";
import Level1Scene from "./level1scene";

export default class GameScene extends Scene {
  //actors
  private declare player: Player;
  private declare currentScene: Scene;
  // tilemap
  private declare map: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap;

  // tilesets
  private declare propsTileSet: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tileset;
  private declare wallTileset: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tileset;
  private declare bgTileset: Phaser.Tilemaps.Tileset;
  // tilemap layers
  private declare propsLayer: Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer;
  private declare bgLayer: Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer;
  private declare wallsLayer: Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer;

  private declare currentMap: string;

  constructor() {
    super({
      key: Scenes.GameScene.key,
    });
    this.currentMap = "level-1";
  }

  init() {
    this.game.events.emit("react__onGameStart");
  }

  create() {
    console.log(this.currentMap);
    this.createTiles();
    this.createLayers();
    this.map.setCollision([1025, 1026]);
    this.createPlayer();
    this.createFullscreenButton();
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
    this.cameras.main.setZoom(2);
  }

  private createFullscreenButton() {
    const fullscreenButton = this.add
      .sprite(this.cameras.main.width, this.cameras.main.height, "fullScreen")
      .setInteractive();

    fullscreenButton.on("pointerup", () => {
      this.toggleFullscreen();
    });
  }

  private toggleFullscreen() {
    if (this.scale.isFullscreen) {
      this.scale.stopFullscreen();
    } else {
      this.scale.startFullscreen();
    }
  }

  update(time: number, delta: number): void {
    this.player.update();
    this.physics.collide(this.player, this.wallsLayer);
    this.physics.collide(this.player, this.propsLayer);
    this.propsLayer.setCollisionBetween(36, 40);
  }
  private createTiles(): void {
    this.map = this.make.tilemap({
      key: this.currentMap,
    });
    this.propsTileSet = this.map.addTilesetImage("props")!;
    this.wallTileset = this.map.addTilesetImage("ground")!;
  }

  private createLayers() {
    this.add.image(0, 0, "bg").setOrigin(0, 0);
    this.propsLayer = this.map.createLayer("props", this.propsTileSet, 0, 0)!;
    this.wallsLayer = this.map.createLayer("ground", this.wallTileset, 0, 0)!;
  }
  private createPlayer(): void {
    this.player = new Player({
      key: "player",
      scale: 1,
      scene: this,
      tag: "player",
      texture: "atlas",
      x: 50,
      y: 0,
      afterCreate: () => {
        console.log("Player is created");
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first I saw a mistake in the `update` function, that might cause problems in the future. You should move these following three lines from the `update` to the `create` function. *(and change the `collide` to the `collider` function call [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Factory.html), or the `overlap` function)*

```js
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.wallsLayer);
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.propsLayer);
this.propsLayer.setCollisionBetween(36, 40);
```

For adding a callback just add a callback function to the specific `collider` function call, like this:

```js
this.physics.add.collider(this.propsLayer, this.player, function(player, tile){
    if(tile.index == 36 ){
      console.info('Collision with tile index 36');
    }
});
```

Comment: Firstly, when I do "collider", I get "Property 'collider' does not exist on type 'ArcadePhysics'. Did you mean 'collide'?
" I get this error.

2nd problem : 
this.physics.collider(this.player, this.wallsLayer);
this.physics.collider(this.player, this.propsLayer);
I can't run these 2 lines except uptade I don't know how much it helps but I get the following error " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isParent')".

Comment: 3.the code you gave worked thank you but I will have one more question with it.
I want to change the level when my player hits, for example, an object with 37id, more precisely, I have a tilemap, I will change it as json, for this I restart the scene and load the level-2 tilemap beforehand.

note : In the tile.index section, the index shows the following error: "Property 'index' does not exist on type 'Tile | GameObjectWithBody'.
  Property 'index' does not exist on type 'GameObjectWithBody'."
but it's work

Comment: Sorry my mistake if you use `collider` or`overlap` it has to be called on the property `add`

Comment: The error *'Tile | GameObjectWithBody'* has to do with phaser type definition and typescript. if you want to get rid of the error/warning could use `// @ts-ignore` above the line to ignore it, or "cast" it to the correct type with somehing like this `(tile as Phaser.Tilemaps.Tile).index`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
So how do I make multiple levels with tilemap.
I tried restarting the scene as you can see but it didn't work.

Comment: Best would be to create a "baseScene", where you create all the basics you need for a level, and for each level make a new scene and inherit from that base scene. Like this you just need to override the map and layer part you want to change. With other words make a Scene for each level. **btw.:** If my answer solved your initial question, please consider accepting it, with the green checkmark under the voting arrows.